# __has_include analog for methods in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Is there any analog preprocessor command for methods in Objective C?
Let's say I have a class `MyClass` in a framework. How can I check if `MyClass.SOME_METHOD` is existing the framework or not and if yes - to run it.
The thing is, when I want to check via:

```
[obj respondsToSelector:@selector(SOME_METHOD:)]
```

if method is not there - the compiler is not compiling.
Can I check it similar to

```
#if __has_include(<MyFramework/MyFramework.h>)
```

but instead of a class to check if method exists there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@selector()` directive does expect an existing method, but it's not the only way to create a selector.

You can use [`NSSelectorFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395294-nsselectorfromstring) to create a selector from a string, either a constant or a variable. The value of this string will not be checked at compile time.

The downside of using this method is that it won't let you know if you make a typo, or if the selector name doesn't match.

Comment: Note that `NSSelectorFromString` returns `0` if no such selector exists at runtime. So check that first, then check with `-respondsToSelector:`.

Comment: I believe NSSelectorFromString only returns 0 if the selector cannot be constructed. "If aSelectorName is nil, or cannot be converted to UTF-8 (this should be only due to insufficient memory), returns (SEL)0." Creating new selectors from strings at runtime is definitely allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely isn't possible to check the equivalent of `-respondsToSelector` at compile-time since that can change at runtime. (This is actually quite common.) Typically what you're describing is performed with [Availability macros](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/marking-api-availability-in-objective-c). Whether that applies to your case depends on the kind of problem you're solving.

What you seem to be describing is the ability to ask Clang if a method is statically believed to be implemented by a class. This is how it determines warnings like `-Wselector`. Note that a lack of this warning doesn't actually mean that the method is implemented (you can promise it and then fail to actually implement it in ways that the compiler can't catch). Getting the warning also doesn't mean that that the selector isn't responded to (it can be, by [creating a method at runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH102-SW1) or [by many other ways](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH105-SW1)). But it's basically what you're describing.

I don't believe there's any Clang feature that will let you check at compile time for the equivalent of `-Wselector` or similar warnings and evaluate a macro based on that. I wouldn't expect it to exist, but if it does, I would study the [Language Extension](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) section of the docs to find it. But I'd first see if Availability macros are what you really want.